# Gradient of a scalar with vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does this expression $\frac{da^{\intercal}a}{da}$ evaluates to $2*a$ or $2*a^{\intercal}$ ? Here $a$ is column vector. Derivation steps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There is no universally accepted convention about whether the gradient is a row vector or a column vector.  In optimization literature, $\nabla f(x)$ is a column vector.  In Terence Tao's Real Analysis books, $\nabla f(x)$ is a row vector.

In Calculus on Manifolds by Spivak, if $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$, then $f'(x)$ is an $m \times n$ matrix.  In particular, if $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, then $f'(x)$ is a $1 \times n$ matrix, a row vector.

Answer (score 0):

This actually confused me also when I was learning. For instance in my signal processing course, I learned it as a row vector, where as in my optimization course I learned it as a column vector. Then later I came to know its just the difference of how you choose to denote the derivative of a scalar with respect to a vector. Here $a^{T}a$ is a scalar and $a$ is a vector. You can choose it either a column vector or to be row vector. The choice should depend on your domain of study and the prevalent notation in that. You can read more about it in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus). The fact how the constant $2$ comes up should be obvious I guess.